# Why does running a game engine script from the text editor cause an error?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

Why does running you Python script using "run script" option in text editor generate an error called "bge module not found", while executing it using <kbd>P</kbd> command doesn't cause any problems?

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having instead of just the general topic.

Comment: Duely noted @Ray Mairlot. Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Run Script' button is not intended for BGE, but for Blender addons and macros. Understand that BGE is a standalone component, it's not part of Blender environment.

This way, importing the module `bge` is not possible when running scripts inside Blender, the same way you can't import the module `bpy` while running scripts through BGE.